# How to store a constant value in a Postgresql script

Tags: postgresql

I need to insert a row in a table, generating its key with `uuid_generate_v4()`, and I need to use that key as a foreign key in a subsequent insert in another table, like:

```sql
\set generated_id uuid_generate_v4()

INSERT INTO
  table1(id)
  VALUES(:generated_id);

INSERT INTO
  table2(id, table1_id)
  VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), :generated_id);
```

But when I read `:generated_id`, every time it gives me a different value, like it is computing it again each time I try to read it.

Is it possible to ask `\set` to not re-compute `uuid_generate_v4()` again? How could this be achieved otherwise?

Comment: \set doesn't compute or re-compute anything.  It stores the function name as text: it is when this function name gets textually substituted into a string and then that string is executed as a query that it gets computed.  You need \gset which will actually invoke the function and store the results (as text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `psql`'s `\gset` to set a variable to the result of a query:

```
SELECT uuid_generate_v4() AS generated_id \gset
```

That will set the variable `generated_id`.

To use the variable in your script, quote it like this:

```
:'generated_id'
```

Comment: I added something to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be to create a temporary table to store that value

```
-- generate id and store it in a temporary table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpval(generated_id uuid);
INSERT INTO tmpval VALUES (uuid_generate_v4());

-- run inserts referencing this table value
INSERT INTO
  table1(id)
  VALUES((SELECT generated_id FROM tmpval));

INSERT INTO
  table2(id, table1_id)
  VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), (SELECT generated_id FROM tmpval));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution is to just do it in one statement:

```
WITH t1_insert AS (
    INSERT INTO table1(id) SELECT uuid_generate_v4() RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO table2(id, table1_id)
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), t1_insert.id
FROM t1_insert;
```